# ObjectListView receiving drag from another model object

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, objectlistview

I used an ObjectListView and a TreeListView
I want to drag the selected object in ObjectListView to the TreeListView and do some stuff on DragDropEvent.

In a classic TreeView we can use GetNodeAt for retrieve the node hover with the mouse point location.
How can I get the current Object in my TreeListView that receive the event DragDrop.

Thanks in advance.
Eric.

Comment: You are probably using the ModelDropped event? Then use ModelDropEventArgs.TargetModel.

Comment: I've set AllowDrop to true, but the ModelDropped was only called when I move something from the TreeListView.
When I move something from the ObjetListView I've no event. It's because the two model Object are different ?

Comment: Not sure about that. Did you read [this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/dragdrop.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tlv.IsSimpleDropSink = true;
    olv.IsSimpleDragSource = true;

    olv.AddObject("Fish");
    tlv.ModelCanDrop += (s,e)=>{e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;};
    tlv.ModelDropped += Tlv_ModelDropped;
}

private void Tlv_ModelDropped(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.ModelDropEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var m in e.SourceModels)
        ((TreeListView)sender).AddObject(m);
}
```